# dask clusters with context manager

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, contextmanager, fire-and-forget

Consider a simple workflow like this:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import time

with Client() as client:
    futs = client.map(time.sleep, list(range(10)))
```

The above code will submit and almost immediately cancel the futures since the context manager will close. It's possible to keep the context manager open until tasks are completed with `client.gather`, however that will block further execution in the current process.

I am interested in submitting tasks to multiple clusters (e.g. local and distributed) within the same process, ideally without blocking the current process. It's straightforward to do with explicit definition of different clients and clusters, but is it also possible with context managers (one for each unique client/cluster)?

It might sound like a bit of an anti-pattern, but maybe there is way to close the cluster only after computations all futures run. I tried `fire_and_forget` and also tried passing `shutdown_on_close=False`, but that doesn't seem to be implemented.

Comment: I think we can agree it's an antipattern - why do you want specifically to use `with` contexts?

Comment: The issue is that I'm operating on a SLURM cluster, where if I don't close the cluster properly, e.g. because my main process is killed due to out of memory error, I have `jobs` (to launch dask workers) left hanging in the queue which need to cleared manually... it's a minor nuisance, so I thought maybe it can be fixed with context manager, but I understand that it's an antipattern now.

Comment: Perhaps use `weakref.finalize` or `atexit`? Also, I think you can attach a callback to your future, to have something happen when its done.

Comment: Thank you for these pointers, I will explore these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some Dask cluster/scheduler types, such as the `dask-cloudprovider` [ECSCluster](https://cloudprovider.dask.org/en/latest/aws.html#elastic-container-service-ecs), the approach described above using the `with` block and `shutdown_on_close=False` would work fine.

Both `ECSCluster` and `SLURMCluster` are derived from [SpecCluster](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/distributed/deploy/spec.html). However, `ECSCluster` passes its `**kwargs` (including `shutdown_on_close`) down to the `SpecCluster` constructor via this call:

```
super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

(see the `ECSCluster` code [here](https://cloudprovider.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ecs.html#ECSCluster))

`SLURMCluster` does not: it calls the `JobQueueCluster` constructor which in turn instantiates `SpecCluster` with only a subset of its parameters:

```
super().__init__(
    scheduler=scheduler,
    worker=worker,
    loop=loop,
    security=security,
    silence_logs=silence_logs,
    asynchronous=asynchronous,
    name=name,
)
```

See the `JobQueueCluster` code [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/blob/main/dask_jobqueue/core.py)

Therefore `SLURMCluster`/`JobQueueCluster` is ignoring `shutdown_on_close` (and other optional parameters). Looks like an update to `JobQueueCluster` would be required for your use case.